# isometry written as a composition of reflections

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, isometry, reflection

im trying to show that the isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by 
$$ F(x,y,z) = (-y,x,z+1) $$
can be written as a composition of $4$ reflections and no less.

I know it can be written with at most $4$ reflections. I know it can't be written using $1$ or $3$ reflections, as that would reverse the orientation. But I'm not sure how I would go about showing that the isometry can't be written as a product of $2$ reflections.

Comment: Please elaborate upon your assertions. I mean please explicitly show how what you claims to hold actually holds.

Comment: Isn't the product of two reflections a rotation?

Comment: A reflection fixes a plane. A composition of two reflections fixes at least a line where those planes intersect. The line could be the line at infinity if the two planes are parallel. However, $F$ fixes only one point at infinity: $[x:y:z:t]=[0:0:1:0]$.

Comment: The case of $1$ and $3$ reflections are discarded, as you said, by noting that these would change orientation, but $F$ preserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are left to show, that it cannot be a product of two reflections. Assume it is. The two reflection planes have nonempty intersection, otherwise they are parallel and in this case it would be a translation, which it isn't. The point in this nonempty intersection is a fixed point. But your map doesn't have any fixed points (look at the third entry).